# What is the meaning by Serialize a graph with phase_train turned to false?

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow

I want to import a TensorFlow model (.pb file) in opencv.

```
import cv2 
cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow("./mars-small128.pb")
```

But this is always giving me this error:

```
opencv/modules/dnn/src/tensorflow/tf_importer.cpp:497: error: (-2:Unspecified error) Input layer not found: Const in function 'connect'
```

I searched on Google for a very long time but didn't get any success to resolve this error. However this thread [link](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/12026#issuecomment-406560628) says:

> please serialize a graph with phase_train turned to false.

But I don't know how to do that. I am exploring [Deep Sort](https://github.com/nwojke/deep_sort) and they have provided these [files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1m2ebLHB2JThZC8vWGDYEKGsevLssSkjo) (.ckpt, .ckpt.meta and .pb file) and also a python [script](https://github.com/nwojke/deep_sort/blob/master/tools/freeze_model.py) to regenerate the .pb file. 
So can anyone tell me where I need to pass that argument **phase_train** or if you have any other solution for that error? 
OpenCv Version -: 3.4.2 and 4.1.0 (Tried on both versions) 
PS. : It would be nice if anyone can explain or give any good link explaining what serializing a graph means.

Comment: serializing the graph is just saving it to disk. 

Well actually it is serialised and saved but that's semantics - serialising means converting it to bytes or text so that it can be written to disk.

Comment: Can you give more detail as to how you generated the .pb file ? Did you freeze the graph ?

Comment: @ma3oun Please see the question again, I have updated the question.

Comment: Try adding the following to line 164 of the python script: `training=False, phase_train=False`
It seems that some operations such as dropout and batch norm don't know if they are in a training phase or not.

Comment: @ma3oun That line is giving error: `TypeError: batch_norm() got an unexpected keyword argument 'phase_train'`

Comment: Try separating the arguments of batch_norm and dropout with two nested calls to arg_scope

Comment: It is still showing the same error. Both batch_norm and dropout are showing `TypeError: dropout got an unexpected keyword argument 'phase_train'`